# PWA fires beforeinstallprompt first time, but after deleting app from desktop, never fires again

Tags: progressive-web-apps

Nothing has changed with the setup and it worked like a charm the first launch.

But now that i've already install to desktop, and then deleted it, it never fires the beforeinstallprompt again.

Lighthouse audit even says everything is configured correctly to prompt user to install. I did Application -> Clear Site Data with all options checked, clear cache and reload, and still nothing.

It's like Chrome is tracking that the desktop install has already happened in its own registry, and there is no way to tell it to reset that.

Anybody have any ideas?

Thanks!
Klaus

Comment: Have you removed the app? Many people do not know to go here to see it. Put this in the address bar: chrome://apps/

Comment: Perfect, thank you Mathias, that did it! Post as answer and i can mark as accepted!

Answer (score 1):

Have you removed the app?
Many people do not know to go here to see it. Put this in the address bar:
 chrome://apps/